# Host a Git repo on Windows server using only OpenSSH/Git

Tags: windows, git, ssh

Is it possible to host a Git Repo that I can pull/push to, which support LFS, using only Git for Windows?

I have tried and failed to get Git Servers such as Bonobo and Gitbucket approved through my IT department.

I am wondering if it is at all possible to have some sort of repo I can interact with solely using OpenSSH/Git for Windows.
I cannot for the life of me find documentation over this... Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) does have:

- [Windows package installation](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-from-package/#windows) (it is a simple executable, no admin privilege needed, o registry modification
- [Git LFS support](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/git-lfs-setup/)

You need to [add a small database](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/database-prep/) beside that executable, and you would get yourself a proper Git repository hosting service, with SSH support, provided the [`sshd` service from the OpenSSH Windows 10 feature is started](https://winaero.com/enable-openssh-server-windows-10/#ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-120)